# Unreported exception java

Tags: java, exception

I am getting an unreported exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown error in the fill method below. From similar posts I read I am assuming that the error originates since the read method has throws Exception but I cannot fix it.

```
public void read(int fileName)  throws Exception 
{
    FileInputStream in = null;

    try 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner("dataset.txt");
        File inFile = new File(in.nextLine());
        in = new FileInputStream(inFile);

    } 
    catch ( Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in) );

    String input;
    input = buf.readLine(); 
    fill(input,buf);
}
```

where fill is defined as:

```
public void fill(String in,BufferedReader buf) 
{
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(input); 
    no = token.countTokens();

    constraints = new Vector[noOfAttributes]; 
    for (int i=0; i < no; i++) 
    {
        c[i] = new Vector(); 
        names = new String[noOfAttributes];
    }

    for (int i=0; i < no; i++) 
    {
        names[i]  = token.nextToken();
    }

    while((in = buf.readLine()) != null) //<----error given here
    { 
        token = new StringTokenizer(input);
        Train example = new Train(no);

    }
    buffer.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `fillData` calls `buffer.readLine()`, which is declared to throw `IOException` - but you neither catch the exception witin `fillData`, nor declare that it might be thrown.

The simplest fix is to change the signature of `fillData` to:

```
public void fillData(String input, BufferedReader buffer) throws IOException
```

I would also strongly recommend *not* closing the reader within `fillData`. Usually, the same code that acquires a resource should be responsible for closing it. A try-with-resources statement is most appropriate here, so in `read`:

```
try (BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))) {
    String input = buffer.readLine(); 
    fillData(input,buffer);
}
```

Even this isn't ideal, however - because you're opening the input stream earlier on. I'd *also* recommend always passing an encoding to the `InputStreamReader` constructor, otherwise it will use the platform default encoding. In Java 7+ you can use `Files.newBufferedReader` which defaults to UTF-8.

Additionally:

- `read` declaring that it throws `Exception` is generally a bad idea; only throw specific exceptions
- Catching `Exception` in `read` is a bad idea; only catch specific exceptions
- Continuing in `read` after a failure is a bad idea - `in` will be null, causing a failure immediately afterwards
- It's very bizarre to have a parameter called `fileName` of type `int`. As it happens, you're not using that anyway - what's the point of it?

Basically *all* of your exception handling and resource management needs a fair amount of work.

Comment: so how does input = buffer.readLine();  work in the read method? it doesn't have a try catch block around it either

Comment: @user4345738: Look at the declaration of your `read` method - it declares that it might throw *any* exception (which is generally a bad idea).

Comment: yes infact I added throws Exception after the fillData method and it works now but is there a better way to do it then please?

Comment: @user4345738: I've given some suggestions in my answer, but really you should read the exceptions best practices part of a good Java book or tutorial, so that you can understand why you got these errors and more details about the best practice. A full explanation would be pretty long here...